# How to use JMeter as a functional testing tool?

Tags: java, rest, api, jmeter, functional-testing

We in our company decided to give JMeter a try for the functional testing of our Http APIs. I see that the JMeter primarily being a performance testing tool, the terminology involved is a bit different like ThreadGroups, Test Fragment, Test Plan and so on. At the end we will want to run these JMeter tests in Jenkins and email the reports. I want something like

```
TestSuite       TotalTestCases    PassedTestCases      FailedTestCases 

FuncTestSuite1           7                 6                    1

FuncTestSuite2           10                8                    2
```

How can I accomplish this kind of test result reporting in JMeter? I can think of creating jmx file for each test case and place them in a folder which represents the testsuite. By this organisation, I could write a utility that runs these JMeter tests and determine pass and fail for each tests, then generate a Junit file that can be published in Jenkins. Is there an alternate way of achieving this with purely JMeter alone or should I settle for this kind of work around to achieve the desired reporting? Is there a way to get pass, fail for each ThreadGroup, so the ThreadGroup can be used as a test case instead of the entire file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of getting JUnit-style reports out of JMeter test execution is running JMeter using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper.

Taurus provides [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) which is capable of converting results of a JMeter test into JUnit format.

The minimal Taurus [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) configuration file would be something like:

```
execution:
  - scenario: mytest

scenarios:
  mytest:
    script: test.jmx

reporting:
  - module: junit-xml
    filename: result
    data-source: sample-labels
```

And you will get a JUnit XML file like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="sample_labels" package_name="bzt">
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test1"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test2"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test3">
            <error message="OK" type="Error">OK
                (status code is 200)
                (total errors of this type: 1)</error>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test4"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test5"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test6"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite1-Test7"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test1"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test10"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test2"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test3"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test4">
            <error message="OK" type="Error">OK
                (status code is 200)
                (total errors of this type: 1)</error>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test5"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test6"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test7"/>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test8">
            <error message="OK" type="Error">OK
                (status code is 200)
                (total errors of this type: 1)</error>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="bzt-11388721" name="FuncTestSuite2-Test9"/>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Taurus execution would be as simple as:

```
bzt test.yaml
```

[image]

And references `test.jmx` script looks like:

[image]

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)